# TCP Socket Multiplexing Send Large Data

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, multiplexing

Got some trouble with TCP socket multiplexing.

```
      //socket is non-blocking
      const int MAX = 4096;
      char *buff[MAX];
      char *p = buff;
      int fd, rvalue;
      rvalue = 0;

      if ( (fd = open(path, O_RDONLY)) < 0 ) {
          return errno;
      } else {
        int didsend, didread;
        int shouldsend;
        while ((didread = read(fd, buff, MAX)) > 0) {
          p = buff;
          shouldsend = didread;
          while ( 1 ) {
            didsend = send(sockfd, p, shouldsend, 0);
            //if send succeeds and returns the number of bytes fewer than asked for then try to send rest part in next time.
            if (didsend < shouldsend) {
              p += didsent;
              shouldsend -= didsend;
              continue;
            }
            //if there is no place for new data to send, then wait a brief time and try again.
            if ( didsend < 0 && (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN) ) {
              usleep(1000);
              continue;
            }
            //if all data has been sent then sending loop is over.
            if (didsend == shouldsend) {
              break;
            }
            //send error
            if ( didsend < 0 ) {
              rvalue = errno;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        close(fd);
        if (didread == -1) {
          return errno;
        }
        return rvalue;
      }
```

Assume I use an I/O Multiplexing function poll() or kqueue(), and non-blocking socket, then if there are only some small data like send a short message, it works fine.

But if it comes to large data, I mean larger than send()'s buffer size, since using non-blocking socket, send() will just send a portion of data, and return how much data it sends, the rest part of data can only be sent in another call of send(), but it takes time, and can't tell how long it will takes. So the second while() is actually a blocking send which using non-blocking socket.

Equivalent to：

```
  //socket is blocking
  const int MAX = 4096;
  char *buff[MAX];
  int fd, n;
  if ( (fd = open(path, O_RDONLY)) < 0 ) {
      return errno;
  } else {
    while ((n = read(fd, buff, MAX)) > 0) {
      if (send(sockfd, buff, n, 0) < 0) {
        return errno;
      }
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
  }
```

So, what is the solution to this, multithreading might work but that's kind of wasting resource maybe.

Comment: Be careful when doing `while ((didread = read(fd, buff, MAX)))`. Remember that `read` returns `-1` on failure, and sinze `-1` is non-zero it is considered "true". Also, if the code shown is not in the `main` function then you have a resource leak as you don't close the file you open.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: that } else { for open seems to add no value

Comment: @kkk yes, but whatever, that's just not my point....

Comment: that's why it is a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: Let's start with a question about your premise.  Why do you want to use non-blocking sockets?  There are valid reasons, but it doesn't appear your code attempts to take advantage of any such reason.  Also, why are you using `usleep` instead of `select` or `poll` ?

Comment: @selbie If a client is downloading a huge file from a host run this program, and it's a large file takes a long time to transfer, so during the transmission, other clients can't access this host cause the process is block by send. So I think non blocking is ok, but non blocking send won't send all the data when the buffer is completely full, then I use a sleep to wait and see if the next time send will have space(that makes another blocking send, even I am using non blocking socket), what I want to know is how to let others be able to access the server during transferring large file.

Comment: One way is that you need to a have a socket thread which does the `accept` and `recv` and worker threads which do the `send`. If you aren't going for multi-threads, there is no way you can have "others access the server" because the one thread is stuck doing the `send`

Comment: @Prabhu Because I can't figure out another way except multithreading I asked this question, so if there is no other way, maybe I should use multithreading, just curious, if the http sever use multithreading, isn't that inefficient? As many many clients request the server at the same time, each one of them consumes a thread(that's only my guess).

Comment: Kevin, you can have a thread pool. Offload the work to them as clients connect. You need not have one thread per connection, which can be inefficient if you want to scale the server application.

Comment: `p += didsent;` After initialisation, p is *always* incremented, but *never reset* to point at buff at every `didread = read(fd, buff, MAX)` outer loop iteration.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks. I fixed it, actually, I didn't use that code, so I didn't compile and check it, may got lots of errors, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the general pattern for a single-threaded server that works with multiple connections and non-blocking sockets.

It's primarily pseudo-code in C and doesn't do the necessary error checking.  But it gives you an idea that for each accepted connection, you keep a struct instance that maintains the socket handle, request parsing state, response stream, and any other "state" members of that connection.  Then you just loop using "select" to wait or having multiple threads doing this same thing.

Again this is only pseudo-code and uses select/poll as an example.  You can get even more scalability with epoll.

```
while (1)
{
    fd_set readset = {};
    fd_set writeset = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_client_connections; i++)
    {
        if (client_connections[i].reading_request)
            FD_SET(client_connection.sock, &readset);
        else
            FD_SET(client_connection.sock, &writeset);
    }

    // add the listen socket to the read set
    FD_SET(listen_socket, &readset);

    select(n + 1, &readset, &writeset, &timeout); // wait for a socket to be ready (not shown - check for errors and return value)

    if (FD_ISSET(listen_socket, &readset))
    {
        int new_client_socket = accept(listen_socket, &addr, &addrlength);

        // create a struct that keeps track of the connection state data
        struct ConnectionData client_connection = {};
        client_connection.sock = new_client_socket;
        client_connection.reading_request = 1;  // awaiting for all the request bytes to come in
        client_connections[number_of_client_connections++] = client_connection;  // pseudo code, add the client_connection to the list
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_client_connections; i++)
    {
        if (client_connections[i].reading_request)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(client_connections[i], &readset))
            {
                char buffer[2000];
                int len = recv(client_connections[i].sock, buffer, 2000, 0);
                // not shown - handle error case when (recv < 0)
                // not shown - handle case when (recv == 0)
                ProcessIncomingData(client_connections[i], buffer, len);  // do all the request parsing here.  Flip the client_connections[i].reading_request to 0 if ready to respond
            }
        }
        else if (client_connections[i].reading_request == 0)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(client_connections[i], &writeset))
            {
                client_connection* conn = &client_connections[i];
                int len = send(conn->sock, conn->response_buffer + conn->txCount, conn->response_size - conn->txCount, 0);
                conn->txCount += len;

                if (conn->txCount == conn->response_size)
                {
                    // done sending response - we can close this connection or change it to back to the reading state
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let's just focus on send(), your code mainly says that we have a flag `reading_request` for each connection, if a single send() in a select() handling loop did't send all data, we don't set `reading_request` to true(that means we won't handle the request in next select() handling loop) and try to send rest data in next handling loop until all data has been sent, right? Sorry if my bad English confuses you. xD

Comment: Correct.  I'm trying to point out that you need to have allocate a data structure to be associated with each socket to maintain the state of the connection, the open file handle that you are reading from, and preferably the temp buffer, (`buff` in your example), instead of using stack variables.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I get you. Thanks for your effective answer.